# how put a unique identification an attribute on PHP

Tags: php, html

this is my third day and I gave up on searching and trying things. I think I need help from this group already *sob. anyway this code will print all profile that is not my friends. I would like to put an id so that when i click add friend it would give me an id of that user and i can manipulate it. thanks guys :)

```
    <?php
      require "php/dbc.php";
      $temp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE username = '$username'");
      $friends = mysql_fetch_array($temp);
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user");

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
      if($row['username'] != $username && in_array($row['username'],$friends)===false){
      echo '<div class="container">';
      echo '<div class="row">';
      echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">';
      echo '<div class="well well-sm">';
      echo '<div class="row">';
      echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">';
      echo '<img src="profile/'.$row['profpicxtn'].'" alt="" " />';
      echo '</div>';
      echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">';
      echo '<h4>';
      echo ucfirst($row['fname'])." ".ucfirst($row['lname']).'</h4>';
      echo '<p>';
      echo '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>'.$row['email'];
      echo '<br />';
      echo ' <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></i>bday</p>';

      echo '<input type="submit" name="name" method="post" c>+1 Add Friend</button>';
      echo '</div>'; 
      echo '</div>';
      echo '</div>';
      echo '</div>';
      echo '</div>';
      echo '</div>';

?>
```

Comment: Can you please post the portions of your code that you've created to actually solve your problem? I assume this must be some client-side/JS code if you want something to appear at the click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

insert add friend button inside the form tag, for setting an id to send with that form you can use hidden inputs and set the value of id inside the hidden input
for example if your id value is equal to $row['id'] you can do it like this

```
<form method="post" action="">
 <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $row['id'] ; ?> />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="+1 Add Friend"/>
</form>
```

keep in mind that you can jump in and out of your `php` script with `?><?php` this makes your code more readable and prevent from weird bugs

Answer (score 0):

Try this revision. There is some questionable stuff going on in your sample code, and provided your sql statement actually returns something (aka you are feeding it proper data) this may help:

```
<?php
require("php/dbc.php");
$temp       =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE username = '$username'");
$friends    =   mysql_fetch_array($temp);
$query      =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        if($row['username'] !== $username && in_array($row['username'],$friends) == false){ ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="well well-sm">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                        <h4>Name</h4>
                        <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i><?php echo $row['email']; ?>
                        <br />
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></i>bday</p>
                        <!--
                        If you have a javascript to run the button, you can use it, otherwise use a form.
                        <button name="name" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" onclick="window.location='whatever.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>'">+1 Add Friend</button>-->
                        <form id="user<?php echo $row['id'];?>" method="post">
                            <!-- Since you are doing a lookup on usernames, I presume username here but id (if available) should be used-->
                            <button name="name" value="<?php echo $row['username'];?>">+1 Add Friend</button>
                        </form>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><?php }
} ?>
```